# I'm getting a typeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, typeerror

I started getting the error when i added the class User and  the turns loop on my main function play(). It used to work when i haven't  included those yet.

The complete error i was getting as:

> File "C:/Users/Dust/Desktop/111/trial.py", line 147, in updateGrid
>
> for i in range(1, int(grid_height-1)):
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Here is my code:

```
PLAYING = "PLAYING"
WAITING = "WAITING"

class User:
    state = ""
    name = ""
    def __init__(self,name, stateParam):
        self.name = name
        self.state = stateParam

    def userInfo(self):
        return self.name

    def getState(self):
        return self.state
    def setState(self, stateParam):
        self.state = stateParam

def play():
    grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_name,p1_char,p2_name,p2_char=getGameSettings()
    displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width)
    updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_char,p2_char)
   # while True:
        #count=0
        #if count < 5:
            #displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width)
            #updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_char,p2_char)
            #count =+1
    userA = User(p1_name, PLAYING)
    userB = User(p2_name, WAITING)  

    turn = 0
    while True:
        user = userA
        if turn % 2 == 0 :
            p_char= p1_char
            user = userA
            userA.setState(PLAYING)
            userB.setState(WAITING)
        else :
            user = userB
            userB.setState(PLAYING)
            userA.setState(WAITING)

        print(".................................................. ")
        print("User to play : ", user.userInfo() , " SEQ : ", str(turn + 1))
        print(".................................................. ")

        try:
            move= int(input('Enter your move: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Plese enter a valid  input.')
        if move < 1 or move > grid_width:
            print('Please  enter a valid input.')
            continue
        break

        updateGrid(grid,move,p_char,grid_height,grid_width)
        turn += 1


def getGameSettings(): 

    #PLAYER 1 NAME
    while True:
        p1_name=input("Enter p1_name: ")
        if len(p1_name) > 15 or p1_name == '': #Validation of input p1_name
            print("Input a valid name. Max of 15 characters only.")
            p1_name=input("Enter p1_name: ")
        else:
            break

    #PLAYER 1 CHARACTER
    while True:
        p1_char=str(input("Enter p1_character: "))
        if len(p1_char) != 1 or p1_char=='' : #Validation of input p1_character
            print("1 character only.")
            p1_char=input("Enter p1_character: ")
        else:
            break

    #PLAYER 2 NAME
    while True:
        p2_name=str(input("Enter p2_name: "))
        if len(p2_name) > 15 or p2_name == p1_name or p2_name == '': #Validation of input p2_name
            print("Max of 15 characters only or choose a different name.")
            p2_name=input("Enter p2_name: ")
        else:
            break

    #PLAYER 2 CHARACTER
    while  True:
        p2_char=str(input("Enter p2_character: "))
        if len(p2_char) != 1 or p2_char == p1_char or p2_char == '': #Validation  of input p2_char
            print("1 character only or choose a different character from player 1")
            p2_char=str(input("Enter p2_character: "))
        else:
            break

    while True: #VALIDATION OF INPUT OF GRID_WIDTH
        try:
            global grid_height
            grid_height=int(input("Enter grid_height(6-10): "))
        except ValueError: #if input is not the right type()
            print('Ivalid input type. Enter an integer')
            continue
        if grid_height > 10 or grid_height < 6: #to check if input is within accepted values
            print('Height must be less than 11 and greater than 5.')
            continue  
        break


    while True: #VALIDATION OF INPUT OF GRID_WIDTH
        try:
            global grid_width
            grid_width=int(input("Enter grid_width: "))
        except ValueError: #if input is not the right type()
            print('Ivalid input type. Enter an integer')
            continue
        if grid_width > 9 or grid_width < 7: #to check if input is within accepted values
            print('Width must be less than 10 and greater than 6.')
            continue  
        break

    #SETTING UP THE GRID
    grid=[]
    for row in range(grid_height): # FOR ROW
        z =[]
        for col in range(grid_width): # FOR COLUMN
            z.append(" ")
        grid.append(z)

    return grid,grid_width,grid_width,p1_name,p1_char,p2_name,p2_char


def displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width):
    for row in range(1,grid_height):
        #print(row) #for checking
        for col in range(grid_width):
            print("|", end="")
            print(str(grid[row-1][col-1]),end = "")
        print("|")
    print(" "+" ".join([str(i) for i in range(1, grid_width+1)]))
    return grid

def updateGrid(grid,move,p_char,grid_height,grid_width):
    for i in range(1, grid_height-1):
        if grid[grid_height-i][move-2] == " ":
            grid[grid_height-i][move-2]= p_char
        else:
            if grid[0][move-1] != " ":
                updateGrid(grid,move,p_char,grid_height,grid_width)
            else:
                continue
        break

    return grid


#def isWin():

#def isDraw():


if __name__ == '__main__':
    play()
```

Comment: in `play()` you are calling the function as `updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_char,p2_char)`. The forth param is `grid_height` in `updateGrid()` definition but you are passing `p1_char` here, which I guess is a string and that is why the issue

Comment: @kuro i can't follow you. What do you suggest the solution should be?

Comment: You should try this `for i in range(1, int(grid_height)-1):` instead of this `for i in range(1, int(grid_height-1)):`

Comment: By doing a simple print statement in your updateGrid I can see that: ```This is grid height: a``` are you expecting it to be an int?

Comment: @Gatts, in `play()` what is `p1_char`? A string? If yes, now look what position you are passing this while calling `updateGrid()`. I think the `updateGrid()` call in `play()` is the culprit

Comment: Yes p1_char is a string. It should be the player's piece that will be placed on the column of their choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid_height` and `grid_width` are both strings the way you've initialized them. You're trying to subtract an `int` from a `str`. You're doing something like this in your code: `" " - 1`. That's not going to work.

Comment: I fixed it. But the way i did it is that i simply removed the the 3rd line of my function  play() because it wasn't needed yet. But  now my problem is, the updateGrid doesn't show any output after entering a move

Comment: First of all, you can fix the problem by changing `int(grid_height-1)` to `int(grid_height)-1`. The command `int(x)`, where x is the string "8", would return the int 8 - instead of removing the line.

Comment: @Gatts Secondly, please ask one question at a time. If your original question has been answered - please ask another one. Also, focus it to the part of the code where the problem is: This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)